# using vscrollbar to scroll a xtragrid

Tags: c#, devexpress

Is it possible to handle `xtragrid's` scrollbar via `DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar`?

something like this:

```
private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     gridView1.vScrollValue=VScrollBar1.Value;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vScrollBar1.Maximum = gridView1.RowCount;

        private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            gridView1.TopRowIndex = vScrollBar1.Value;
        }
        private void gridView1_TopRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vScrollBar1.Value = gridView1.TopRowIndex;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  vScrollBar1.Maximum = gridView1.RowCount - gridView1.RowCount / 17;

    private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        gridView1.TopRowIndex = vScrollBar1.Value; 
    } 

    private void gridView1_TopRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
       vScrollBar1.Value = gridView1.TopRowIndex;
    } 

    gridView.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(gridView1_TopRowChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a smooth vertical scrolling with the `xtragrid`. The scrolling is performed by rows.

To do that, use the `Scroll` event of the `VScrollBar`:

```
   private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
   {     
        GridViewInfo viewInfo = gridView1.GetViewInfo() as GridViewInfo;
        if (viewInfo != null)
        {
            gridView1.TopRowIndex = (int)(
                      (gridView1.RowCount - viewInfo.RowsInfo.Count)
                      *
                      (1 + (1.0 * vScrollBar1.LargeChange / vScrollBar1.Maximum))
                      *
                      vScrollBar1.Value / vScrollBar1.Maximum
                     );
        }
    }
```

#### Where:

- `viewInfo.RowsInfo.Count` = visible rows count

  - `gridView1.RowCount - viewInfo.RowsInfo.Count` = maximum index that can be set to be the top.
- `vScrollBar1.Value / vScrollBar1.Maximum` = percentage scrolled of the scrollbar.

Comment: i've found it and put it as a comment above .it worked smooth for me.

Comment: What I meant by smooth is scrolling pixel by pixel. Scrolling by row works. Put your solution as an answer and accept it so that it will help others. As comment it's not readable.